# How to Install Postgresql 11 in Amazon Linux AMI?

Tags: linux, postgresql, amazon-web-services

How do I install Postgresql 11 on Amazon Linux 2018.03 (specifically, not  AMZ Linux 2) on Elastic Beanstalk?

I want to install a package and not manually build a binary. If an autoscale machine boots and has to build the entire PG binary, it'll take significantly longer on a t2/t3.micro.

I'm looking for `pg_dump`.

[Edit] Making more verbose, explain why building does not work for my situation.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The key was the PGDG is no longer available to Amazon Linux's `yum` [since 9.3](https://yum.postgresql.org/repopackages.php) so the individual pieces must be installed.

```
  # Remove old Postgres
  yum remove -y postgresql postgresql-server

  # Install Postgres 11
  yum install -y https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/11/redhat/rhel-6-x86_64/postgresql11-libs-11.4-1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64.rpm
  yum install -y https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/11/redhat/rhel-6-x86_64/postgresql11-11.4-1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64.rpm
  yum install -y https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/11/redhat/rhel-6-x86_64/postgresql11-server-11.4-1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64.rpm
```

[edit]
Replace the `11.4` in each link above with any version you need available at https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/11/redhat/rhel-6-x86_64/

Comment: For Postgresql 12 tools you can run this: 

    `sudo yum install -y https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/12/redhat/rhel-6-x86_64/postgresql12-12.2-2PGDG.rhel6.x86_64.rpm https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/12/redhat/rhel-6-x86_64/postgresql12-libs-12.2-2PGDG.rhel6.x86_64.rpm`

Comment: this doesnt work.. 
I just get the error "Cannot open xyz.rpm"

Answer (score 17):

```
sudo yum update
sudo amazon-linux-extras install postgresql11
```

Comment: This only works for AMZ Linux 2 which has the amazon-linux-extras. It is the default OS for ElasticBeanstalk today though, so very valid.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like there's no PostgreSQL 11 pre-built binary distribution for Amazon Linux. The way I solve it was to build from source code:

`wget https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/source/v11.5/postgresql-11.5.tar.gz`

`tar zxvf postgresql-11.5.tar.gz`

`cd postgresql-11.5`

`./configure --without-readline`

`make`

`make install`

By default, it will install pg_dump into `/usr/local/pgsql/bin/pg_dump`.

Comment: I wanted to avoid building it if it was at all possible since it's a small machine (t3.nano) and that can take time.

Answer (score 4):

This is an extended version of @nitsujri answer. I can't comment their comment, so I will create new answer here.

Install prerequisites:

```
sudo yum install readline-devel
sudo yum group install "Development Tools"
```

Download PostgreSQL source code and install the distro:

```
wget https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/source/v11.5/postgresql-11.5.tar.gz
tar zxvf postgresql-11.5.tar.gz
cd postgresql-11.5
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Add this line to your `~/.bashrc`. After that relogin to an EC2 instance.

```
export PATH=/usr/local/pgsql/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: How can i start the service of postgresql?